# React hash routing and sub routing

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router

I have currently route structure for example
`#/home`
`#/dashboard`

but how can I implement sub-route or child route such as

`#/home/dashboard`

```
<HashRouter>
              <main className="h-100">
                <Switch>
                  <Route exact path='/home' component={Login} />
                  <Route path='/dashboard' component={Dashboard} />
                </Switch>
              </main>
            </HashRouter>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply change the route to sub routes, for example

```
<Route exact path='/home/subroute' component={Login} />
```